# Running ParallelTable[] with ssh

Tags: parallelization, remote-access, kernel-startup

I have a ParallelTable[] code, that runs perfectly fine on my local machine, but to speed things up a notch, I want to run it on a remote server. I configured everything in Evaluation>> Parallel Kernel Configuration>> Remote Kernels. But when I run my ParallelTable[] code, the terminal pops up, I enter my password and connect to the remote machine, but the notebook never launches the kernels, it just says launching kernels forever.